# how to add a hyphen in between a string

Tags: java

I have the following sting xxxxx, I want to add a hyphen like x-xxxx, how can I do so using Java?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can make use of [`String#substring()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int%29).

```
String newstring = string.substring(0, 1) + "-" + string.substring(1);
```

You'll only need to check the [string length](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#length%28%29) beforehand to avoid `IndexOutOfBoundsException`, but that's nothing more than obvious.

Comment: If you have a StringBuilder or StringBuffer you can also use insert: myStringBuilder.insert(1, '-');

Comment: +1 for pointing out the exception possibility. It wasn't obvious to me; my example does not handle the general case.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming

```
String in = "ABCDEF";
String out;
```

Then, ***any of***:

```
out = in.replaceFirst(".", "$0-");
```

or

```
out = String.format("%1$s-%2$s", in.substring(0,1), in.substring(1));
```

or

```
out = in.substring(0,1) + "-" + in.substring(1);
```

or

```
out = new StringBuilder(in).insert(1, '-').toString();
```

will make `out = "A-BCDEF"`.

Comment: Regular expressions and format specifiers? Your first two examples seem arcane to me!

Comment: @isme: I agree :-). I thought posting these different methods would be useful for more complex replacements though, to make readers aware of what possibilities there are.

Comment: OMG I didn't know you can refer to `$0`. Makes sense, of course, but I just never thought about it. Learned something new, +1!

Answer (score 4):

`String` is an immutable type in Java, meaning that you can't change the character sequence it represents once the `String` is constructed.

You can use an instance of the `StringBuilder` class to create a new instance of `String` that represents some transformation of the original `String`. For example, add a hyphen, as you ask, you can do this:

```
String str = "xxxxx";
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(str);
builder.insert(1, '-');
String hyphenated = builder.toString(); // "x-xxxx"
```

The `StringBuilder` initially contains a *copy* of the contents of `str`; that is, `"xxxxx"`.

The call to `insert` changes the builder's contents to `"x-xxxx"`.

Calling `toString` returns a new `String` containing a *copy* the contents of the string builder.

Because the `String` type is immutable, no manipulation of the `StringBuilder`'s contents will ever change the contents of `str` or `hyphenated`.

You can change what `String` instance `str` *refers to* by doing

```
str = builder.toString();
```

instead of

```
String hyphenated = builder.toString();
```

But never has the contents of a string that `str` refers to changed, because this is not possible. Instead, `str` used to refer to a instance containing `"xxxxx"`, and now refers to a instance containing `"x-xxxx"`.

Comment: @lain Elder. Good description for immutable object behavior.

Answer (score 1):

```
String xxx = "xxxxx";
String hyphened = xxx.substring(0,1) + "-" + xxx.substring(1);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
String orgStr = "xxxxx";
String newStr = orgStr.substring(0,1) + "-" + orgStr.substring(1)
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's another way:

```
MaskFormatter fmt = new MaskFormatter("*-****");
fmt.setValueContainsLiteralCharacters(false);
System.out.println(fmt.valueToString("12345"));
```

Comment: This solution is bad, because its work only fixed length.